# JSQMessageViewController - Add a label inside chat bubble, on the side of the text

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using JSQMessageViewController for a simple chat app I'm building, and since I'm new in Swift and iOS development in general, I need some help on how to achieve this:

I want to add a timestamp inside the chat bubble. I read that I need to change some related xib files, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

I found [this](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1551), and **marcuschoong**'s comment gets pretty close, but I'm not sure how to find these xibs' classes, and how to connect the IBOutlets to that class (I don't have any experience in Objective C either). I need the timestamp for both incoming and outgoing messages. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 xib files depending on the type of message, incoming or outgoing:

```
JSQMessageCollectionViewCellIncoming.xib
JSQMessageCollectionViewCellOutgoing.xib
```

Both have the same structure: avatar, bubble container, cellTopLabel, cellBottomLabel...

In your case, you can move either cellTopLabel or cellBottomLabel into the bubble container (and adjust their constraints). If you use cellBottomLabel, you'll need to modify the following method in order to show the timestamp for every message (by default the timestamp is only displayed every 3 messages, "indexPath.item % 3"):

```
- (NSAttributedString *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JSQMessage *message = messages[indexPath.item];
    return [[JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter sharedFormatter] attributedTimestampForDate:message.date];
}
```